# Bing maps geocode service cannot be called from own web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, azure, bing-maps

I have a own web service that wrapped the geo bing maps geocode web service. This geocode web service is hosted in a Azure web role. When I try to make the call, I get the following error:

There was no endpoint listening at http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/GeocodeService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.. Unable to connect to the remote server

When I test it from a winforms testapp, using the same created WS client proxy the result is correct.

It looks that a call from my own webservice to the Bing maps webservice is not allowed somehow...

Any clue what is wrong.... ?

Comment: Try Fiddler2 http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ it will let you inspect the requests and response

Comment: Good idea! I'll check this now

Comment: In the WinForms app, I see the request coming into Fiddler. Using the web app during the postback, I don't see any traffic coming into Fiddler, it just waits for 10 secs and then the error from the original posting is shown.

Comment: Update: I enabled WCF tracing for the request/response. The request from web and from WinForms service proxy client are the same, so there is no corruption or whatever in the request message....

Comment: Update2: I made a regular asp.net web app, using the same code, same created WS client proxy and that works. But when I host it as an Azure web role, the error occurs again. It looks like this error only occurs during hosting by Azure (locally)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. We use a proxy here in the office (set to 'Automatically detect settings'). The proxy doesn't allow calling from Azure web role to external web services. When using direct internet connection, it worked perfectly.

Comment: So this was an error that occurred while you were using the Azure Compute Emulator locally, not actually running in the cloud?

Comment: Exactly. This app was running locally.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip, the Bing Maps REST services has much better geocoding than the SOAP services. They are also faster and lighter weight. I have a blog post on how to use the REST services in .NET here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/bing-maps-rest-service-net-libraries/

just a tip though, when using the REST services from server side code you can set the user ip address information in the REST request. Set this to 127.0.0.1. This will trick the geocoder into using the default geocoding algorithm rather than using a localized algrothim for what ever country your server is hosted in.

Comment: Thx Ricky, I'll write this down as a good refactoring task for the next iteration.